# Правильны ли знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, тире

Постепенно пропадала уверенность в себе, а кроме того – я терял связь с внешним миром.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, знаки поставлены верно, хотя в основном вводные слова выделяются запятыми, а не тире. Но в данном случае запятую после союза а поставить нельзя, и для усиления пунктуации после вводного сочетания поставлено тире. Вот подходящий пример:

> Тему для рассказа можете взять произвольную, но, главное, чтобы было интересно; Детали можно опустить, а главное – чтобы было занимательно (запятую после союза а поставить нельзя, и для усиления пунктуации после вводного сочетания поставлено тире).
>   ([Лицей](http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726-210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html))